# Getting an SQL syntax error on a section of my insert code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im currently making a PHP submit form that allows records to be added to a phpmyadmin database. I have created this code and have been stuck all night trying to work out whats wrong with it

When i typed the names of the fields in the form (for dummy data) i got this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Password', 'Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Address', 'Email', 'Card
>   Number', 'CCV' )' at line 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Insert Users</title></head>
<body>
<h2>Insert User Confirmation</h2>

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post"/> <br> 
<?php
    require_once('connection.php');

    echo    "<label for='memberID' >Member ID:</label>";
    echo    "<input type='text' name='memberID' id='memberID' />";
    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

    echo    "<label for='username' >Username:</label>";
    echo    "<input type='text' name='username' id='username' />";
    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

    echo    "<label for='password' >Password:</label>";
    echo    "<input type='password' name='password' id='password' />";
    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

    echo    "<label for='fName' >Firstname:</label>";
    echo    "<input type='text' name='fName' id='fName' />";
    echo    "<br /><br />";     

    echo    "<label for='lName' >Lastname:</label>";
    echo    "<input type='text' name='lName' id='lName'  />";
    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

    echo    "<label for='address' >Address:</label>";
    echo    "<input type='text' name='address' id='address'  />";
    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

    echo    "<label for='email' >Email:</label>";
    echo    "<input type='text' name='email' id='email'  />";
    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

    echo    "<label for='cardnumber' >Card Number:</label>";
    echo    "<input type='text' name='cardnumber' id='cardnumber'  />";
    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

    echo    "<label for='ccv' >CCV:</label>";
    echo    "<input type='text' name='ccv' id='ccv'  />";
    echo    "<br /><br />"; 

    echo    "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />";
    echo    "<input type='reset' value='Clear' />";
    echo    "<br /><br />"; 
?>
</form>


<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
        echo 'Please Register';
    }
    else {
        $memberID = $_POST['memberID'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $fName = $_POST['fName'];
        $lName = $_POST['lName'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $cardnumber = $_POST['cardnumber'];
        $ccv = $_POST['ccv'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO `members` (MemberID, Username, Password, FirstName, LastName,     StreetAddress, Email, CardNumber, CCV) VALUES ('$memberID', '$username, '$password', '$fName', '$lName', '$address', '$email', '$cardnumber', '$ccv' )";
        mysqli_query($connection, $query)
        or  die(mysqli_error($connection));

        $rc = mysqli_affected_rows($connection);
        if ($rc==1)   
                    {
                    echo '<h4>The database has been updated with the following details: </h4> ';
                    echo 'MemberID: '.$memberID.'<br />';
                    echo 'Username: '.$username.'<br />';
                    echo 'Password: '.$password.'<br />';
                    echo 'First Name: '.$firstname.'<br />';
                    echo 'Last Name: '.$lastname.'<br />';
                    echo 'Address: '.$address.'<br />';
                    echo 'Email: '.$email.'<br />';
                    echo 'Card Number: '.$cardnumber.'<br />';
                    echo 'CCV: '.$ccv.'<br />';
                    }
        else
                    {   
                    echo '<p>The data was not entered into the database this time.</p>';   
                    }
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear God, do *not* store CC data...

Comment: Make your query multiline to see better which part is at fault

Comment: FYI, I've retagged the question because Microsoft SQL Server is a different product that Oracle MySQL.

Comment: If you do store store credit card numbers you must follow PCI guidelines. These guidelines are set by the payment card industry and define what you can and cannot do.

Comment: So much for [PCI Compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/index.php)

Comment: Guys no need to worry this is not going to be an actual website... its just for a university assignment. My teacher said there was no issues with this. But I now stand informed and will change it.

Comment: If they're teaching you these reckless habits in university, they should be barred from teaching anything to do with credit card processing. Imagine if medical school was this slapdash. "Washing your hands before surgery? Nah. Just wipe your hands on your pants." You wonder how [gigantic hacks](http://www.cnbc.com/id/101964168) happen? It **starts with this**.

Comment: For another example of [bad teaching about CC info](https://twitter.com/spazef0rze/status/513705914067853313/photo/1)

Answer (score 4):

I can't add comments  due too low reputation so I answer here:

Have you noticed the missing ' after '$username?

Try

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `members` (MemberID, Username, Password, FirstName, LastName,     StreetAddress, Email, CardNumber, CCV) VALUES ('$memberID', '$username', '$password', '$fName', '$lName', '$address', '$email', '$cardnumber', '$ccv' )";
```

Comment: ... after all that it was just a (') I hate coding so much.

Thank you

Comment: This is not a quoting problem. This is just **insane**. When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. That will take care of any quoting issues automatically. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Any answer that uses string interpolation is wrong regardless of the form of the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Change your insert, you've done it wrong I think

INSERT INTO `members`(`MemberID`, `Username`, `Password`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `StreetAddress`, `Email`, `CardNumber`, `CCV`) VALUES ('$memberID', '$username', '$password', '$fName', '$lName', '$address', '$email', '$cardnumber', '$ccv')